# Linux One Liner to return eth name, ip, mac and subnet

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have been trying to combine two queries I have into one. I am trying to get an output of IP info which will get compared to another query against the host file and eventually dumped into a database. My commands have to be simple one liners due to how they are deployed.  I can get what I need with these two, but is there a way to combined them.  The ip show puts out a multiline output and not sure how to combined the lines.

```
ip -o addr show | awk '/inet/ {print $9, $4}' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
ip -o addr show | awk '/link/ {print $2, $13}' | grep -v lo
```

Top gives most of the info and bottom gets the mac. This gives both but it is multi line so not sure how to awk out the values I need.  Any good thoughts or tricks?  Still new on the linux/bash.

```
 ip -o addr show | grep -i 'ether\|inet'
```

Example of an ip -o addr show command

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN \            link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
2: eth0    inet x.x.x.x/24 brd x.x.x.x scope global eth0
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1    inet x.x.x.x/24 brd x.x.x.x scope global eth1
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2    inet x.x.x.x/27 brd x.x.x.x scope global eth2
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth4    inet x.x.x.x/24 brd x.x.x.x scope global eth4
7: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: eth5    inet x.x.x.x/24 brd x.x.x.x scope global eth5
8: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: eth6    inet x.x.x.x/28 brd x.x.x.x scope global eth6
9: eth7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input so we're not guessing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not 100% as accurate as the original, but it works with your input:

```
ip -o addr show | awk '/inet/ && !/127.0.0.1/ {print $9, $4} /link/ && ! /lo/ {print $2, $13}'
```

If you want the output on one line,
then you can wrap the above command in `echo $(...)` like this:

```
echo $(ip -o addr show | awk '/inet/ && !/127.0.0.1/ {print $9, $4} /link/ && ! /lo/ {print $2, $13}')
```

Comment: This is definitely closer to what I was looking for. Still a multi line output though. Not sure if there is a way around that in a one liner.

Comment: Janos thanks for the update. That helps out quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try egrep instead of grep

```
ip -o addr show | egrep -i "ether|inet"
```

Comment: This returns the same values at ip -o addr show but loses the first loopback line.